# integer arithemetic rounding

Tags: integer, integer-arithmetic

Tried to find a way to do easy rounding only using integer types. Found the following solution:

Example 1 - rounding up

```
Value1=260
Value2=305

Tmp1=(10 * Value1) / Value2 = 8.52 = 8 (integer)
Tmp1=(Tmp1 + 5) / 10 = (8 + 5) / 10 = 1.3 = 1 (integer)
```

Example 2 - rounding down

```
Value1=76
Value2=305

Tmp1=(10 * Value1) / Value2 = 2,49 = 2 (integer)
Tmp1=(Tmp1 + 5) / 10 = (2 + 5) / 10 = 0.7 = 0 (integer)
```

Are there better ways to do this?

Maybe this helps someone else who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which programming language ? Usually you have round functions to do that operations.
Java Example:

```
//.00 added to get 2 decimals
double Value1=260.00;
double Value2=305.00;

int Tmp1,Tmp2;

//To round from 5,1 to 5:

Tmp1 = (int) Math.floor(Value1/Value2);

//To ceil from 5,1 to 6:

Tmp1 = (int) Math.ceil(Value1/Value2);
```

Comment: ansi c - running on embedded cpu - no floating point unit at all. in most cases i try to avoid the use of c libraries, as in case you need to add the complete library to your code, even if you only want to use one or two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
int round(float myValue) {  [Test Values: 0.51, 0.49, 2.7, 3.3]
int rounded=myValue*2  [1,0,5,6]
int toAdd=myValue % 2  [1,0,1,0]
rounded=rounded/2      [0,0,2,3]
rounded=rounded+toAdd  [1,0,3,3]
return rounded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming numbers are unsigned numbers, and assuming round-up-on-half behavior is desired, things are easy if either of two conditions applies.  If the divisor known to be a multiple of two, simply compute (n/(d/2)+1)/2.  If the divisor is not known to be a multiple of two but the dividend is known not to be too large, compute ((2*n/d+1)/2.  If neither condition applies, it will be necessary to individually handle more cases.